# 'System.NullReferenceException' with templates c#

Tags: c#, list, templates, nullreferenceexception

I have a code where class State holds a template.
class Cell is actually my T.
I'm trying to add an object of type State to my list, and it gives me an error as if it points to null, even though I debug and see it has good values, especially as I expect.

```
public abstract class Searcher<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    List<State<T>> solution;
    public List<State<T>> backTrace(State<T> n , ISearchable<T> searchable)
    {
        while (! ( n.getPrevious().Equals(searchable.getInitialState())))
        {
            if (n != null)
                solution.Add(n); //ERROR, NULL EXCEPTION }}

    "'System.NullReferenceException'.."
```

what's weird is that it gets past the if state, and still won't add it to the list because it gives me that error. my State class is:

```
public class State<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    public T state;         // the state represented by a string/cell
    private State<T> cameFrom;  // the state we came from 
    public State<T> getPrevious()
    {
        return cameFrom;
    }
```

any help..?

Comment: So where is `solution` defined? That's the only other thing that could be null here. Try `List<State<T>> solution = new List<State<T>>();`.